# Referencing an object title in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, foreach

I have an object (example below) that I am converting to an array but the conversion code drops the key and need to reference the key in a future for each loop but i cant figure out how to keep the key.

```
 let json = {
    "6250": {
        "property1": "...",
        "property2": "..."
    },
    "6177": {
        "property1": "...",
        "property2": "..."
    },
    "5870": {
        "property1": "...",
        "property2": "..."
    },
    "4297": {
        "property1": "...",
        "property2": "..."
    },
    "5743": {
        "property1": "...",
        "property2": "..."
    }
}

function json2array(json){
    var result = [];
    var keys = Object.keys(json);
    keys.forEach(function(key){
    result.push(json[key]);
});
    return result;
}

var array = json2array(json);

array.forEach(function(elem, i) {
    Output.push(name, elem["property1"], elem["property2"]]);
});
```

the "`name`" should be `6250` on the first loop for example.

Comment: Are you sure it is an array and not an object? It seems you have a syntax error. I mean, are you sure the first `[` is really a `[` and not a `{`?

Comment: Why the last `object` don't have an `ID` like the others, please review your structure, clarify if it is an `array` of objects or just an `object`.

Comment: updated the code for clarifications. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) seems to have the all of the functionality that you need. It will return an array of [key, value] for each property of the input object. This means the output will be a 2D array.

```
let array2d = Object.entries(json);
array2d.forEach(function (elem) {
    Output.push(elem[0], elem[1].property1, elem[1].property2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best and cleanest way to iterate a json, hope it helps.

```
let dataJson =  {
"6250": {
     "property1": "...",
     "property2": "..."
 },
 "6177": {
     "property1": "...",
     "property2": "..."
 },
 "5870": {
     "property1": "...",
     "property2": "..."
 },
 "4297": {
     "property1": "...",
     "property2": "..."
 },
 "5743": {
     "property1": "...",
     "property2": "..."
 }
}

for (let x in dataJson){
  //x is the current key
  console.log(x);
  //getting the values of the current key
  console.log(dataJson[x]);
}
```

Comment: i feel like iterating through the json is the way to go but I can't get it down. i just need to endup with output.push([ID,propert1,property2]) and i cant seem to get there

Answer (score 0):

I hope I am understanding your problem correctly. To get all the values into a **single** array you could use an [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) on the [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) like so:

```js
let json = { "6250": { "property1": "...", "property2": "..." }, "6177": { "property1": "...", "property2": "..." }, "5870": { "property1": "...", "property2": "..." }, "4297": { "property1": "...", "property2": "..." }, "5743": { "property1": "...", "property2": "..." } }

let result = Object.keys(json).reduce((r,c) => {
  r.push(c, ...Object.values(json[c]))
  return r
}, [])

console.log(result)
```